# How can I charge an iPod with an unsupported cable?

Tags: cydia, lightning

I bought 2 usb cables to sync and charge.
The problem is that my iPod Touch says "unsupported cable" and will not charge (but can sync over usb).

Is there a cydia hack to stop the os detecting the unsupported cable and start charging?

Or a mod to the cable itself?

Comment: Buy a supported cable. Spend a few more dollars. Solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block the warning with an app called Pop-Up Blocker, but if you are charging with too much juice, it's on you if you fry your iPod.

You can also look for an app called "ReSupported" if you are having problems with video out cables.

Comment: it looks like it just blocks the warning, don't charge

Answer (score 1):

[Apple iPod, iPhone (2g, 3g), iPad Dock connector pinout](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml)

Not all cables are the same for the different generation iPods/iPhones.  You got the wrong cable.